# How do I add a custom sub menu menu under Woo-commerce marketing?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

I am developing a plugin and I want to add a menu under the woo-commerce marketing menu like the coupons and overview submenus. How am able to archieve that?

I did this but it didn't work.

```
add_submenu_page(
    'admin.php?page=wc-admin&path=/marketing',
     __( 'Sub Menu' ),
    'manage_woocommerce',
    'sub-menu-slug',
    'sub_menu_page_callback'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If available the `$GLOBALS[ 'menu' ]` array holds data for each top level menu item in the dashboard, and in the sub array for the Woocommerce "Marketing" menu item, key 2 has the value you're looking for: `"woocommerce-marketing"`.

So with that your `add_submenu_page` should look like the below to make your sub menu item show up under the Woocommerce Marketing menu item:

```
add_submenu_page(
    'woocommerce-marketing',
     __( 'Sub Menu' ),
    'manage_woocommerce',
    'sub-menu-slug',
    'sub_menu_page_callback'
);
```